# xcode6.01Lost Connection to "iPhone"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i create a Widget ,it has been succeed debugging in many iphones,but this one~
how to resolve this problem? "Debug > Attach to Process > " was not worked
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try run the app again after getting this message? It is telling the application is in background mode and not suspended or killed yet.If the app is in suspended mode kill it and try to run again.I do this usually it works for me.Chill